# :limit parameter don't seem to work in migrations on Rails 6.1.4.1

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

After generating migrations, I always change the default `t.timestamps` , because other applications to the Postgres database have issues with the large precision that this default timestamps has. Also I like the database to set the timestamp (instead of Rails doing this for me), hence the `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps limit: 3, default: -> { "timezone('utc', now())" }, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I recently upgraded to Rails 6.1.4.1 (coming from Rails 5.2)

The `limit: 3` setting does not seem to work anymore. It does not give any warnings, but on looking into the Postgres database, the datatype is `timestamp` and not `timestamp(3) as it normally is after running such migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has changed changed the name of that setting from `:limit` to `:precision`.

So you should change your code to:

`t.timestamps precision: 3, default: -> { "timezone('utc', now())" }, null: false`

Or you can change the Base class of the Migration class to the older version

`ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`